# Getting error message when i click on a link on master page in asp.net 4.0

Tags: master-pages, asp.net-4.0

**Script link on master page:**

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationURL"].ToString()%>Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**Default.aspx page**

```
<a class="level1" href="VideoLibrary/VideoUpload.aspx">Video Library</a>
```

When i click on this hyperlink i got following error message:

[image]

What should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the aspx code of the VideoUpload.aspx page?

Comment: actually i put debugger point on page load on VideoUpload.aspx page and it not goes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use expression in `<head runat="server">` tag. What you need to add `<script>` via `Page.Header` property.

```
 HtmlGenericControl script = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
 script.Attributes.Add("src", System.Configuration
            .ConfigurationManager
            .AppSettings["ApplicationURL"] 
                 + "Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js");
 script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
 Page.Header.Controls.Add(script);
```

Comment: It's working fine for my project.Thanks a lot for you reply.but one thing i want to tell u that we can use expression in `<head runat="server">` tag.i have done in a sample application.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the Script tags inside PlaceHolder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
   <script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationURL"].ToString()%>Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```